# Using the double angle formula, it's characteristics and applications

Tags: trigonometry

So I know the double angle formula is

$$
2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha = \sin(2\alpha)
$$

I have this equation :

$$
2\sin(mx+ny)(\cos(mx+ny))m
$$

Now according to the answers sheet if I use the double angle formula I get

$$
2m\sin(2mx + 2ny)
$$

But according to the formula, wouldn't I have to multiply only $\alpha$ by $2$?

According to me, I would get

$$
sin(2mx+2ny)m, ~~\text{without the 2 upfront.}
$$

Can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong? Or what I'm not understanding correctly?

Does the formula

$$
2 \sin \cos\alpha \cos \alpha = \sin(2\alpha) ~~~\text{imply}~~ 2\sin(2\alpha) ~~~\text{?}$$

A photo of the problem for reference:
[image]

Comment: The answer sheet is wrong. You are correct.

Comment: One more typo in a textbook !

Comment: Thanks ! May you please check the picture that i uploaded and still tell me if im right? Maybe i'm missing something or i dont know